# Loading MySQL dump file with bin extension

Tags: mysql

I know how to restore MySQL DB with *.sql files.

But i don't know how to import *.bin files. Content in this file is:

```
123456789|www.site-name.com
123789456|www.go.com
123987456|www.g1.net
987865432|www.site.org
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*.bin files are mysql logs. You can view these files with the command `mysqlbinlog`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqlbinlog.html

**BUT** looking at the content of the file, it appears to be just plain text file with | as a column separator.  (The default column separator in mysql is TAB.)

You can load file with the following command

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/file.bin'
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html